# How to create a Projector with shadows in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, spotlight, projector

I would like to simulate a real life projector that acts as a spotLigt, with a tinted texture.

The spotlight cookie property only affects the intensity of the light and not the color, while the Projector shader has no shadows.

Do I have to implement my own projector shader, if so how?
Or is there a way to attach a texture to a spotLight that also tints the colors of it?

(this is Unity 5.3)

Answer (score 0):

You could use both of them pointing at the same direction. You also need to [add a square cookie](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-LightCookie.html) to the Light.

Comment: the problem is that the projector lits the bacface of the objects and not casting shadows.
If both the light component and a Projector component is attached, it's still the same unfortunately.

Comment: I have figured this out and you are right. Except one thing is missing. The Projector component could be attached to a spotlight, and the shader has to be set to multiply. This way it seem to be working perfectly.

Comment: so it does work with the multiply projection shader, when there are no other lights in the scene. when I add other lights the multiplication cancels out their light as well.

Comment: If you use a different gameobject for the projector and the spotlight, but still facing the same direction, is the problem persist?

Comment: Projector component does not work as a real projector, its only a kind of texture projection. It should act as a ligthsource with varying colors.
What I am actually looking for probably is a colored light cookie but its only working with the alhpa channel. My current idea is to have 3 spotlightts for red green and blue, and use the rgb texture channels seperately. But I thought it would be easier